# Disable Eslint in NuxtJS

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I want to disable eslint for nuxt while i am writing some feature beacuase it's always annoying to take care of spaces & indentations.

How can i disable eslint in `nuxt.config.js` and turn on back later ?

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt3: Remove `eslintPlugin()` (or whatever you `import from 'vite-plugin-eslint'`) from `vite.plugins` in `nuxt.config.js`.

Nuxt2: Remove `'@nuxtjs/eslint-module'` from `buildModules` in `nuxt.config.js`.